# Do I have to use apphub or codepush for updating my application's code instead of doing it myself

Tags: react-native, code-push, app-hub

Can I place the bundle file on my server for the application to load and update some implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can build yourself or refer Apphub example for self hosting via http://docs.apphub.io/v1.0/docs/self-hosting